# Preproccess every HTML elements before appending it to DOM in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to translate my app, without make any changes to the HTML.

I want to create an interceptor, that receive every element BEFORE it's appended to DOM. Then I can take the text nodes, and translate them.

Something like that:

```
app.config(function (DOMIntercepter){
  DOMINtercepter.onElementAdded(){
    TranslateElementContent()
  })
})
```

For example, when an Angular directive read an HTML template file, I want to translate the file, before the directive get the template.

Do you any better idea for that?

Comment: If you only want to translate your HTMLs I would use angular-translate: https://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: This is good. But i need to add `translate` attribute to the HTML. I'm searching for alternative that not requesting to add this attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an $http interceptor:

```
app.factory('htmlInterceptor', function() {
  return {
    response: function(res) {
      if (res.headers('content-type').match(/html/)) {
        res.data = manipulateHtml(res.data);
      }
      return res;
    }
  }
});

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('htmlInterceptor');
});
```